# subfigure caption format differs for \captionof

Tags: captions, subcaption

When I place a subfigure caption using `\captionof`, the format differs from the one appearing when placed via `\caption` inside a subfigure environment.

I suppose this is a bug in the `\captionof` command? Trying to force it via `\captionsetup` doesn't work either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \caption{A}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=parens}
\captionof{subfigure}{B}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I would place `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space}` (note the use of `subfigure`, not just `sub`) in the preamble and then use `\begingroup
\captionof{subfigure}{B}
\endgroup`. Note the use of the group.

Comment: ...perhaps even add `size=small` to the `\captionsetup`.

Comment: @Werner - I take it the group is to prevent a subsequent \caption misplaced outside a figure from running (no error message)?

Comment: @JohnKormylo: `\caption` uses `\@captype` to know what caption to set. `\captionof` redefines `\@captype` and then sets a usual `\caption`. Without a limited scope, you could use `\caption` *outside* a float. It's unlikely to happen, but you'll see a warning to that effect in the `.log` when compiling without grouping `\captionof`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner,  the `subfigure` instead of `sub` part already did the trick! Should have read the `subcaption` manual more carefully. 
Also, maybe I should have been more clear: I do not plan on placing the subcaption somewhere outside a float, it was just the most simple way to reproduce the error. I actually use it in an xlabel of a PGFplot, so no need for a grouping there. Adding \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space} to the preamble solved it globally, although I still consider it odd behavior that two formats exist otherwise.
You could put it as an answer

Answer (score 6):

`\captionof{subfigure}` was never meant to work correctly. (IMHO it should give an error message instead.) `\captionof` is only valid for main environments which offer captions, like `figure`.

If one need sub-captions for non-floating environments, I recommend using `\captionsetup{type=...}` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \caption{A}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=parens}
\begingroup
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
        \caption{B}
    \end{subfigure}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

BTW: I recommand using `\captionsetup{type=...}` plus `\caption` instead of `\captionof` anyway, even when used for main captions.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/44/

Comment: Since caption.sty v3.4g (2020-01-02) the usage of `\captionof` with a sub-type produces an error instead of weird behavior.