# Letters for figure captions

Tags: captions, subcaption

I would like to represent each figure with a letter caption. For the first row, all figures should have a caption of Figure 1(a), ... Figure 1(d), and Figure 2(a), ... Figure 2(d) for the second row.

Is this possible?

```
\documentclass[a1paper,fontscale=0.43]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures
\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mancrop1.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg1im1.png}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg1im3.png}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg1im2.png}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mancrop2.jpg}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg2im1.png}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg2im3.png}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.24\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg2im2.png}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
Figures caption.
\end{center}

\end{poster}

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable?  So, you want each of your figures to have a subcaption like `Figure 1(a)`. Do you also want to have a common caption for all subfigures like `Figure 1 Caption text`?

Comment: Yes, I would like to make each figure have a caption of Figure x(i), where x is the row, and i is a letter from a to d. I also want them to have a common caption underneath the figure.

Comment: Should the commom caption also get a number?

Comment: A number for the common caption is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I assume that you want to stay with a non-floating set of images, I have applied the [advice given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/310400/134144) to your example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Figure~\arabic{figure}(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}



\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \captionsetup[sub]{labelformat=parens}
  \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mancrop1.jpg}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg1im1.png}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg1im3.png}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg1im2.png}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}

    \refstepcounter{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{mancrop2.jpg}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg2im1.png}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg2im3.png}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.24\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{seg2im2.png}
      \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \captionof*{figure}{Figures caption.}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```